# Map JSON object into TypeScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typescript

I am returning an array of objects from server using AJAX JQuery, an example

```
[{"Name":"Name1","ResultSet":[{"Id": 1,"Name":"Name1"}, {"Id": 2,"Name":"Name2"}]},{"Name": "Name11", "ResultSet": [{"Id": 11, "Name": "Name11"}, {"Id": 22, "Name": "Name22"}]}]
```

Also, I have the following TypeScript object I want to map

```
interface IResult {
   name: string;
   resultSet: any;
}

export class Result implements IResult {
    constructor(public name: string, public resultSet: any) { }
}
```

The way I am processing the results,

```
dataService.execute(function (results) {
    $(results).each(function (index, element) {
        console.log(element.Name);
            $.each(element.ResultSet, function (key, value) {
                $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(key + ' - ' + value);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Inside VS 2013, the compiler complains that:

```
The property 'Name' does not exist on value of type 'Element'.
```

Is there a way to map the returned collection of objects to an array of TS Result objects?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I ended up looping as follows:

```
var result = <Array<IResult>>results;

$.each(result, function (index, item) {
      // item is Result instance
      // item.name
      console.log(item.name);

      // item.resulSet
      $.each(item.resultSet, function (key, val) {
            // val is single Object (one result)
            $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                  // k,v => key/value for each property on result
                    console.log(k + ' - ' + v);
            });
      });
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your interface definition for IResult the properties are lower case, but you try and access them using upper case. Since your JSON has upper case change IResult to:

```
interface IResult {
   Name: string;
   ResultSet: any;
}
```